# configure: error: libpq is not installed or libpq is old

Tags: database, linux, postgresql, ubuntu, pgpool

I'm trying to install pgpool-II in Ubuntu 13.10 environment. I'm following [this](http://pgpool.projects.pgfoundry.org/pgpool-II/doc/tutorial-en.html) tutorial to get it done.

I get below error.

> configure: error: libpq is not installed or libpq is old

From the docs.

> Note: pgpool-II requires libpq library in PostgreSQL 7.4 or later
>   (version 3 protocol). If configure script displays the following error
>   message, libpq library may not be installed, or it is not of version
>   3.
>
> configure: error: libpq is not installed or libpq is old
>
> If the library is version 3, but above message is still displayed,
>   your libpq library is probably not recognized by configure script.
>
> configure script searches for libpq library under /usr/local/pgsql
>   libaray. If you have installed PostgreSQL to a directory other than
>   /usr/local/pgsql, use --with-pgsql, or --with-pgsql-includedir and
>   --with-pgsql-libdir command line options when you execute configure.

I'm using below command to fix it as instructed but it does not work.

```
./configure --with-pgsql-includedir /usr/lib/
```

I also followed [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27009/pgpool-install-libpq-is-not-installed-or-libpq-is-old) from Database Administrators Stack Exchange too.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When compiling programs that require `libpq`, the Ubuntu package that must be installed is [`libpq-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpq-dev).

---

That being said, concerning
pgpool II, it doesn't need to be compiled from source because it's available as a package in the main repository:

```
$ apt-cache search pgpool2
pgpool2 - connection pool server and replication proxy for PostgreSQL
```

so it would be easier to run

```
sudo apt-get install pgpool2
```

to install the package.

Answer (score 3):

1 - If that alone doesn't do the trick, try making sure pg_config is on the PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-[version]/bin
```

2- > ./configure

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.

```
./configure --with-pgsql-includedir=/usr/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the main reason, it is because we lack of some information.
   if the postgresql was installed with YUM. confirm that the /usr/pgsql-[version]/lib/ /usr/pgsql-[version]/include/ /usr/pgsql-[version]/bin/ are exists in your server

> yum install postgresql10-server postgresql10-devel postgresql10-libs
>   -y

then

> ./configure --prefix=/opt/pgpool-II/ --with-pgsql=/usr/pgsql-10/bin/
>   --with-pgsql-includedir=/usr/pgsql-10/include --with-pgsql-libdir=/usr/pgsql-10/lib

Answer (score 0):

Got same error (error: libpq is not installed or libpq is old) on fedora while trying to configure pgpool by executing ./configure

It gets solved by installing postgres development package which has libpq as its dependency.

For fedora : dnf install postgresql-devel

Use your system pacakge manage to install postgres-devel